# node/vue.js unit test with a promise , how to write it correctly?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, promise, mocha.js, sinon

Basically , I am trying to test the following vex/action :

```
export default {
  login (context, payload) {
    return vueAuthInstance.login(payload.user, payload.requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      if (JSON.stringify(response.data) !== '{}') {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    })
  }
}
```

In which I have a dependency **vueAuthInstance** I need to stub/mock ...
It's being called and it has a login function, with two argments, and it returns an object ( response) with a data property

```
  vueAuthInstance = {login: sinon.stub().withArgs({email: 'email', password: 'password'}, 'options').return({data: 'user_data_with_token'}) }
```

my login function is actually like calling the vueAuthInstance stub,
so I should be able to write

```
actions.login(context, payload).then((response) => {
  expect(response).to.eql(true)
})
```

but I am locked in writingg a correct test

```
describe('login', () => {
   const payload = {user: {email: 'john.doe@domain.com', password: 'john123'}}
   sinon.stub(vueAuthInstance, 'login').withArgs(payload).returns(true)
   it('should return successful login', () => {
     actions.login(context, payload).then((response) => {
       expect(response).to.eql(true)
     })
   })
 })
```

I get an error :

```
 actions.js login
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

to complete the context, here are the complete files ...

**@/services/auth.js  =======================**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
 aimport { VueAuthenticate } from 'vue-authenticate'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

const vueAuthInstance = new VueAuthenticate(axios, {
  baseUrl: '/'
}) a

export default vueAuthInstance
```

**@/vuex/getters.js =======================**

```
import _ from 'underscore'

export default {
  isAuthenticated: state => state.isAuthenticated,
}
```

**@/vuex/mutation_types.js =======================**

```
export const IS_AUTHENTICATED = 'isAuthenticated'
export const CURRENT_USER_ID = 'currentUserId'
```

**@/vuex/actions.js =======================**

```
  import { IS_AUTHENTICATED, CURRENT_USER_ID } from './mutation_types'
  import getters from './getters'
  import vueAuthInstance from '@/services/auth.js'

  login (context, payload) {
    payload = payload || {}
    return vueAuthInstance.login(payload.user, payload.requestOptions)
    .then(  login: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      payload = payload || {}
      return vueAuthInstance.login(payload.user, payload.requestOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        // check response user or empty
        if (JSON.stringify(response.data) !== '{}') {
          commit(IS_AUTHENTICATED, { isAuthenticated: true })
          commit(CURRENT_USER_ID, { currentUserId: response.data.id })
          return true
        } else {
          commit(IS_AUTHENTICATED, { isAuthenticated: false })
          commit(CURRENT_USER_ID, { currentUserId: '' })
          return false
        }
     })
   }
```

**/test/unit/specs/vuex/actions.js =======================**

```
  describe('login', () => {
    it('should return successful login', () => {
    })
  })

  1/ I must stub or spy my dependency vueAuthInstance
```

Comment: No, it doesn't return that object. It returns a *promise* for it. Use [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) to create one as the return value of the mock.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi mentioned, the returned object should be a promise , so the correct test is :

```
      describe('loginUser', () => {
        var sandbox, payload, response
        beforeEach(() => {
          sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
        })
        afterEach(() => {
          sandbox.restore()
        })

        it('should return successful login', () => {
          payload = {user: {email: 'john.doe@domain.com', password: 'john123'}, requestOptions: {}}
          response = {data: {id: 1, name: 'John Doe', email: 'john.doe@domain.com', created_at: '2017-11-02T07:56:36.405Z', token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjMiLCJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiBMb2dpbiBEb2UiLCJhZG1pbiI6dHJ1ZX0.VHK2sCbj5nKJ8oC44UTHuhQHXEdPN8zjKjaFT0OZ-L'}}
          sandbox.stub(vueAuthInstance, 'login').withArgs(payload.user, payload.requestOptions).returns(Promise.resolve(response))

          return actions.login(store, payload)
          .then((result) => {
            expect(result).to.eql(true)
            expect(store.commit).to.have.been.calledWith(types.IS_AUTHENTICATED, { isAuthenticated: true })
            expect(store.commit).to.have.been.calledWith(types.CURRENT_USER_ID, { currentUserId: response.data.id })
          })
        })
       it('should return invalid login', () => {
          payload = {user: {email: 'john.doe@domain.com', password: 'john999'}, requestOptions: {}}
          response = {data: {}}
          sandbox.stub(vueAuthInstance, 'login').withArgs(payload.user, payload.requestOptions).returns(Promise.resolve(response))

          return actions.login(store, payload)
          .then((result) => {
            expect(result).to.eql(false)
            expect(store.commit).to.have.been.calledWith(types.IS_AUTHENTICATED, { isAuthenticated: false })
            expect(store.commit).to.have.been.calledWith(types.CURRENT_USER_ID, { currentUserId: '' })
          })
        })
      })
```